# How to do a collapsible/ expandable with a curve connected join to the grid using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have several grid columns like as shown below. I want to create a detail section in a collapsible/ expandable mode with a curve connected join to the grid box. The same applied for all grid when click the expandable icon

[image]
[image]

How to do this. I am able to create a grid but how to create a detail section in a collapsible/ expandable mode with a curve connected join to the grid box

```css
.top-panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.grid-header .count {
  font-size: 23px
}

.grid-body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.count {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ff9800;
}

.label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .top-panel {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .top-panel {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top-panel">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-header">
      <div class="count">23450</div>
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">XXXXX</div>
      <div class="count">34</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">YYYYY</div>
      <div class="count">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-header">
      <div class="count">23450</div>
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
    </div>
     <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">XXXXX</div>
      <div class="count">34</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">YYYYY</div>
      <div class="count">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-header">
      <div class="count">23450</div>
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
    </div>
     <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">XXXXX</div>
      <div class="count">34</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">YYYYY</div>
      <div class="count">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-header">
      <div class="count">23450</div>
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
    </div>
     <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">XXXXX</div>
      <div class="count">34</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">YYYYY</div>
      <div class="count">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-header">
      <div class="count">23450</div>
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
    </div>
     <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">XXXXX</div>
      <div class="count">34</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-body">
      <div class="label">YYYYY</div>
      <div class="count">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Add more grids as needed -->
  
</div>
```

Comment: I have implemented something like this in the past, using Bootstrap's Accordion component. The main "trick" was to place them into a flexbox container, so that the `order` property could be used to change the visual order of the elements - putting four buttons first, followed by four collapse elements, then four buttons again, etc. Using SASS the necessary rules using `:nth-child()` selectors can be automatically generated, and in "high enough" quantity to cover whatever your possible maximum number of elements is.

Comment: Rearranging the elements via `order` has the advantage that this only happens visually - screen reader users will still get the elements read in the _correct_ order (providing you hide the visual rearranging from them.)

Comment: @CBroe do you have any samples

Comment: And for the stuff that "joins" the current button and its panel, I used absolute positioned pseudo elements, applied to the currently active button resp. `.accordion-header` element. With were you want rounded corners here and where not, it might need some fiddling, but in general you should be able to achieve it that way,